# Different amount in operation and its effects

Tags: manageofferoperation

I have a `manage_offer` operation (https://horizon.stellar.org/operations/70271497528152065) on the Stellar live network. It has `amount=5.8869963` and `price=0.4689155`, so from the other side amount should be `amount*(1/price)=12.55449286705174`. This transaction has one effect (successful trade, https://horizon.stellar.org/operations/70271497528152065/effects) which has 
`sold_amount=12.2645807` and it doesn't match.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I had set a wrong price. Actually, it should have been `1/price=2.13258039028`. Due to this mistake best matching order was completed.